# Java MySQL Query using JDBC

Tags: java, php, mysql, jdbc

So i've been working a project of mine and i'm trying to make highscores for the players of my project. Currently the highscores works to display every skill and their combined level, exp and level per skill. What i'm trying to do at the moment is have it display the prestige level of every skill. So i'm trying to cycle through all the skills prestige levels 1 by 1. Here's what I have currently:

```
        try {
            if (!connect(HOST, DATABASE, USER, PASS)) {
                return;
            }

            String name = player.getUsername();

            PreparedStatement stmt1 = prepare("DELETE FROM "+TABLE+" WHERE username=?");
            stmt1.setString(1, player.getUsername());
            stmt1.execute();

            PreparedStatement stmt2 = prepare(generateQuery());
            stmt2.setString(1, player.getUsername());
            stmt2.setInt(2, player.getRights());

            stmt2.setInt(3, 0); // game mode number
            stmt2.setInt(4, player.getSkills().getTotalLevel(player)); // total level

            stmt2.setLong(5, player.getSkills().getTotalXp());

            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                stmt2.setInt(6 + i, (int)player.getSkills().getXp()[i]);
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 25; ii++) //this is what i added and wont work
                stmt2.setInt(7 + ii, player.prestigeManager.getTotalTimesSkillPrestiged(ii));
            stmt2.execute();

            destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the query builder :

```
public static String generateQuery() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("INSERT INTO "+TABLE+" (");
        sb.append("username, ");
        sb.append("rights, ");
        sb.append("mode, ");
        sb.append("total_level, ");
        sb.append("overall_xp, ");
        sb.append("attack_xp, ");
        sb.append("defence_xp, ");
        sb.append("strength_xp, ");
        sb.append("constitution_xp, ");
        sb.append("ranged_xp, ");
        sb.append("prayer_xp, ");
        sb.append("magic_xp, ");
        sb.append("cooking_xp, ");
        sb.append("woodcutting_xp, ");
        sb.append("fletching_xp, ");
        sb.append("fishing_xp, ");
        sb.append("firemaking_xp, ");
        sb.append("crafting_xp, ");
        sb.append("smithing_xp, ");
        sb.append("mining_xp, ");
        sb.append("herblore_xp, ");
        sb.append("agility_xp, ");
        sb.append("thieving_xp, ");
        sb.append("slayer_xp, ");
        sb.append("farming_xp, ");
        sb.append("runecrafting_xp, ");
        sb.append("hunter_xp, ");
        sb.append("construction_xp, ");
        sb.append("summoning_xp, ");
        sb.append("dungeoneering_xp) ");
        sb.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        sb.append("overall_prestige, ");
        sb.append("attack_prestige, ");
        sb.append("defence_prestige, ");
        sb.append("strength_prestige, ");
        sb.append("constitution_prestige, ");
        sb.append("ranged_prestige, ");
        sb.append("prayer_prestige, ");
        sb.append("magic_prestige, ");
        sb.append("cooking_prestige, ");
        sb.append("woodcutting_prestige, ");
        sb.append("fletching_prestige, ");
        sb.append("fishing_prestige, ");
        sb.append("firemaking_prestige, ");
        sb.append("crafting_prestige, ");
        sb.append("smithing_prestige, ");
        sb.append("mining_prestige, ");
        sb.append("herblore_prestige, ");
        sb.append("agility_prestige, ");
        sb.append("thieving_prestige, ");
        sb.append("slayer_prestige, ");
        sb.append("farming_prestige, ");
        sb.append("runecrafting_prestige, ");
        sb.append("hunter_prestige, ");
        sb.append("construction_prestige, ");
        sb.append("summoning_prestige, ");
        sb.append("dungeoneering_prestige) ");
        sb.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

This is the error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 32
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2578)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1298)
    at com.RuneDivinity.game.cores.mysql.Highscores.run(Highscores.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Your insert statement is basically invalid.  You might want to include the actual SQL you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

> ```
>    sb.append("dungeoneering_xp) ");
> ```

has to be

```
sb.append("dungeoneering_xp, ");
```

> sb.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

is twice in your code::

Remove simply the first from the top.

Comment: Would I then add the new values "dungeoneering_prestige" to the appended values?

Comment: You have to enter the equla number of question marks to the query and also add the same number of Variables. So you have to count the number of Columns you add to the query and the number of question marks.

Comment: Gotcha! I'll change the query with that and see if it still gives me the same error